# Reading in a seqence from a text file in Common Lisp

Tags: file, lisp

I want to read in a textfile and make it a sequence and pass it on.  How do I do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
(with-open-file (stream "filename.txt")
  (format t "~a~%" (read-line stream)))
```

The text file is like this:

```
Hello this is a sentence.
Hello this is second sentence.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(with-open-file (in "filename.txt")
  (with-output-to-string (out)
    (loop :for line := (read-line in nil) :while line :do
       (write-line line out)))))
```